# wpf привязка (обновление данных)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

есть класс `Project` (модель) с некиеми методами:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ReadAndVerify
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [XmlIgnore]
        private static string pathToFile = @"..\..\Xml\Project.xml";

        [XmlIgnore]
        private string title;
        [XmlIgnore]
        private DateTime startDateForProject;
        [XmlIgnore]
        private DateTime finishDateForProject;

        public string Title { get { return title; } set { title = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Title"); } }
        [XmlElement("StartDate")]
        public DateTime StartDateForProject { get { return startDateForProject; } set { startDateForProject = value; RaisePropertyChanged("StartDateForProject"); } }
        [XmlElement("FinishDate")]
        public DateTime FinishDateForProject { get { return finishDateForProject; } set { finishDateForProject = value; RaisePropertyChanged("FinishDateForProject"); } }

        public Project() { }

        public Project(string title,DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate)
        {
            Title = title;
            StartDateForProject = startDate;
            FinishDateForProject = finishDate;
            //DayOfProject = 10;
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<MyDictionary> getTheurrentPercentageOfTheDayOfProjectExecution(List<Project> projects)
        {
            ObservableCollection<MyDictionary> result = new ObservableCollection<MyDictionary>();
            foreach (Project _project in projects)
            {
                // Сколько всего дней для проекта (100%)
                int maxDate = _project.FinishDateForProject.Subtract(_project.StartDateForProject).Days;
                // Сколько прошо дней (кол-во)
                int curentDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_project.StartDateForProject).Days;
                // Текущий процен пройденых дней
                result.Add(new MyDictionary(_project.Title, curentDate * 100 / maxDate));
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Во `ViewModel` есть переменная `project`, которая содержит в себе все проекты с xml файла (биндится `DataGrit Mode = TwoWay`) для редактирования данных каждого проекта. Отображение идет в другом окне через прогресс бары + текстблок отдельной переменной, которая заполняется методом `getTheurrentPercentageOfTheDayOfProjectExecution()` класса `Project`. Класс `MyDictionary` имеет реализацию интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `Key` - это название проекта, `Value`- это процент прогресс бара.

Проблема: если я изменяю список проектов, и на кнопке `сохранить` вызываю заново метод `getTheurrentPercentageOfTheDayOfProjectExecution`, то почему прогресс бары и названия с коллекции ObservableCollection автоматом не подтягиваются? (Возможно что-то еще из кода понадобится...)

Comment: А добавляете вы новые данные небось как `Projects = getTheurrentPercentageOfTheDayOfProjectExecution()` (или как там у вас привязанная коллекция называется...)? Если так, то неверно. Привязки в WPF производятся по сути в момент инициализации. Когда вы запускаете проект в котором есть некий `ListBox` привязанный к `MyProject`, то вы должны работать только с этим экземпляром `MyProject`. Теперь посмотрите на свой метод: `result = new ObservableCollection<MyDictionary>();`. Это равнозначно `Projects = new ObservableCollection<...>()`. Вы не добавляете данные, вы подменяете коллекцию!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Прогресс бары забинжены на `data`, где `data = Project.getTheurrentPercentageOfTheDayOfProjectExecution(_projects);` GridView` забинжено на `_projects`, где `private List<Project> _projects = Project.GetProjects();`. переменная `data` зависит от `_projects` (параметр). Как мне сделать, чтобы `data` изменялась при изминении `_projects`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если бы я мог привязать возвращаемое значение метода, то я мог бы привязать и там и там к `_projects `. Это возможно сделать?

Comment: Ну вот вы и сбиваете всю привязку, ибо переинициализируете `data`. Если что то уже привязали, то не делайте `= new ...();`, используйте ссылку на этот объект. То есть не `data = SuperMethod();`, а `foreach (var item in SuperMethod()) data.Add(item);`. Также пару советов: 1. Избавьтесь от статика!!! 2. В вашем методе `ObservableCollection` избыточна, вам нечего обновлять, вы им лишь составляете новые данные. Используйте обычный `List<>`, его будет достаточно. 3. Пересмотрите имена своих методов, `getTheurrentPercentageOfTheDayOfProjectExecution` - это ужас!!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пишу так: `data.Add(new MyDictionary("asd", 50));` **появляется отображение нового итема**; Пишу так: `for (int i = 0; i < _projects.Count; i++)
            {int maxDate = _projects[i].FinishDateForProject.Subtract(_projects[i].StartDateForProject).Days; int curentDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_projects[i].StartDateForProject).Days;            data.Add(new MyDictionary(_projects[i].Title, curentDate * 100 / maxDate)); }` - **И ничего не происходит (хотя если вывести все `data.Key`, то все там поменяно, просто не отображается**

Comment: Где вы это пишите? В методе? И что такое `data`, точней тип какой? Если это привязанная ObservableCollection то все должно работать. P.S. Ваш комментарий лучше прикрепить к вопросу. И вообще, какая у вас задача, добавить значение или его обновить? Что то мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь обновить элементы в коллекции...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ обновить пытаюсь (старые значения вытер, новые добавил)

Comment: Если обновление, то тут не надо нечего удалять, работайте с тем, что уже есть. К примеру у вас есть привязанная `ObservableCollection<MyVM>` в `MyVM` вы реализуете все, что связанно с этим объектом (всякие имена, даты и прочую инфу), также если эта VM обновляется, то не забываем про `INotifyPropertyChanged` на обновляемые свойства. Также для обновления вы внутри VM делаете публичный метод (прим: `Update(){...}`) в котором реализуете логику обновления этого объекта. Все, вам остается вызвать этот метод к примеру так: `foreach (var item in data) item.Update();`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ваши ответы и замечания помогли, хоть сделал и по своему, но все же огормнешее спасибо!! можете ответом написать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь повторно инициализировать уже привязанную и инициализированную коллекцию.

То есть если у нас есть

```
public ObservableCollection<string> TestData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

с привязкой `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}"/>`.

То если мы напишем `TestData = new ObservableCollection<string>();` - наша привязка пропадет, ибо мы привязались к старой копии объекта.

Добавлять данные нужно через метод `Add` или его аналогу. Если у нас есть некий метод, который генерирует данные и возвращает новую коллекцию, то стоит пройтись по ней циклом, добавив так все данные в привязанную коллекцию. Пример:

```
foreach (var item in AddData())
    TestData.Add(item);
```

---

Теперь что касается обновления. В MVVM (да и вообще в ООП) принято разбивать всю логику по своим классам, которые отвечают только за этот объект. Скажем есть у нас человек, делаем класс `class Person{}`. Человек имеет руки, ноги, голову, пусть это будут наши свойства (`public Hand[] Hands {get; set;}`, `public Head Head {get; set;}` ...). Также человек может выполнять какие то действия, например идти, это по сути тоже метод класса `Person` (`public void Walk(int speed){...}`). Как видите все это относится к человеку логично это все реализовывать именно в классе человека, а не относить скажем ходьбу к классу сердца. Также и у вас, вы делаете коллекцию неких объектов у которых есть своя логика, так почему бы не написать метод обновления внутри этой ViewModel?

Пример:

Делаем некий класс (VM):

```
public class TestData
{
    public TestData(string name, int percent)
    {
        Name = name;
        Percent = percent;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }

    public void Update() => Percent++;
}
```

Делаем коллекцию с тестовыми данными:

```
public ObservableCollection<TestData> TestCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TestData>
{
    new TestData("Item 1", 0),
    new TestData("Item 2", 1),
    new TestData("Item 3", 2),
    new TestData("Item 4", 3)
};
```

Далее предположим, что мы ее привязали, все у нас работает. Надо теперь обновить данные, мы делаем следующее:

Если всю коллекцию, то:

```
foreach (var testData in TestCollection)
    testData.Update();
```

Если один элемент:

```
TestCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Item 3")?.Update();
```

Как видите мы нечего не передобавляем, мы работаем с тем, что уже имеем. Так что советую вам тоже попробовать это реализовать, отказавшись от каких то статичных методов...

Удачи в изучении WPF!